# OOXML : keep images displayed after moving the header content to to the body

Tags: openxml-sdk, openxml, word-2010

I am using open XML SDK and I want to move the content of content control (containing images) from the header to the body, the problem that images does not show after moving. After copying the content control content I am adding the image parts in this way :

```
foreach (var headerPart in wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
                        {
                            SdtBlock sdtToSave = this.FindSdtBlock(contentControlTag, headerPart );
                            if (sdtToSave != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var imagePart in headerPart.ImageParts)
                                {
                                    ImagePart newPart = mainPart.AddImagePart(imagePart.ContentType);
                                    this.GenerateImagePartContent(newPart, imagePart.GetStream());                                                                }
                                 }
                        }
private void GenerateImagePartContent(ImagePart imagePart, Stream partStream)
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(partStream);
            partStream.Close();
        }
```

then if I add this lines :

```
Paragraph paragraph = sdtToSave.SdtContentBlock.GetFirstChild<Paragraph>();
                                    Run run = new Run();
                                    paragraph.Append(run);
                                    run.Append(this.GenerateDrawing(mainPart.GetIdOfPart(newPart)));


private Drawing GenerateDrawing(String relationshipID)
        {
            Drawing drawing1 = new Drawing();

            Inline inline1 = new Inline() { DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U, DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U, DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U, DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U };
            Extent extent1 = new Extent() { Cx = 152400L, Cy = 152400L };
            EffectExtent effectExtent1 = new EffectExtent() { LeftEdge = 0L, TopEdge = 0L, RightEdge = 0L, BottomEdge = 0L };
            DocProperties docProperties1 = new DocProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "Image 1" };

            NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties nonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties1 = new NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties();

            A.GraphicFrameLocks graphicFrameLocks1 = new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true };
            graphicFrameLocks1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");

            nonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties1.Append(graphicFrameLocks1);

            A.Graphic graphic1 = new A.Graphic();
            graphic1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");

            A.GraphicData graphicData1 = new A.GraphicData() { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" };

            Pic.Picture picture1 = new Pic.Picture();
            picture1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("pic", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture");

            Pic.NonVisualPictureProperties nonVisualPictureProperties1 = new Pic.NonVisualPictureProperties();
            Pic.NonVisualDrawingProperties nonVisualDrawingProperties1 = new Pic.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)0U, Name = "AddTo_Blink.png" };
            Pic.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties nonVisualPictureDrawingProperties1 = new Pic.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties();

            nonVisualPictureProperties1.Append(nonVisualDrawingProperties1);
            nonVisualPictureProperties1.Append(nonVisualPictureDrawingProperties1);

            Pic.BlipFill blipFill1 = new Pic.BlipFill();

            A.Blip blip1 = new A.Blip() { Embed = relationshipID };

            A.BlipExtensionList blipExtensionList1 = new A.BlipExtensionList();

            A.BlipExtension blipExtension1 = new A.BlipExtension() { Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}" };

            A14.UseLocalDpi useLocalDpi1 = new A14.UseLocalDpi() { Val = false };
            useLocalDpi1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("a14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main");

            blipExtension1.Append(useLocalDpi1);

            blipExtensionList1.Append(blipExtension1);

            blip1.Append(blipExtensionList1);

            A.Stretch stretch1 = new A.Stretch();
            A.FillRectangle fillRectangle1 = new A.FillRectangle();

            stretch1.Append(fillRectangle1);

            blipFill1.Append(blip1);
            blipFill1.Append(stretch1);

            Pic.ShapeProperties shapeProperties1 = new Pic.ShapeProperties();

            A.Transform2D transform2D1 = new A.Transform2D();
            A.Offset offset1 = new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L };
            A.Extents extents1 = new A.Extents() { Cx = 152400L, Cy = 152400L };

            transform2D1.Append(offset1);
            transform2D1.Append(extents1);

            A.PresetGeometry presetGeometry1 = new A.PresetGeometry() { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle };
            A.AdjustValueList adjustValueList1 = new A.AdjustValueList();

            presetGeometry1.Append(adjustValueList1);

            shapeProperties1.Append(transform2D1);
            shapeProperties1.Append(presetGeometry1);

            picture1.Append(nonVisualPictureProperties1);
            picture1.Append(blipFill1);
            picture1.Append(shapeProperties1);

            graphicData1.Append(picture1);

            graphic1.Append(graphicData1);

            inline1.Append(extent1);
            inline1.Append(effectExtent1);
            inline1.Append(docProperties1);
            inline1.Append(nonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties1);
            inline1.Append(graphic1);

            drawing1.Append(inline1);
            return drawing1;

        }
```

all images are shown at the end of body.

From the OXML SDK productivity tool I can see that bookmarks are used to insert images inside a paragraph.

To summarize, I want to know how to keep images when moving content controls from header to the body.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your image part to the mainPart, it will be given a relId which is unlikely to be the same as the relId it had in the headerPart.  So you'll have to adjust the relId in the drawing (Embed = relationshipID) to match.

Comment: That was exactly what I need to do: changing the embed property of the Blip to match the added imagePart relationShipId.